# Python exercise 3.3 complete code

Tags: python

I am unable to get the script to return the letter grade. The code allows me to enter the grade, but it does not return the letter grade. It currently is error free, but fails to return response.

```
#Given (1) score, and (2) grade
# For scores between 0.0 - 1.0, this programs prints the letter grade
# For scores enter out of the range of 0.0- 1.0 this program will print an error message
# Use try/catch exception handling to gracefully exit on values outside of the specified range

import sys


score= input ("Enter numeric value of score: ")
score = 0.0-1.0
# Convert input from default string value to integer
floatScore = float (score)
try:
     intScore = int (score)


except:
    if score > 1.0:
        print ("Bad Score")


# Use conditional loop to display letter grade based on user-supplied score


# Print letter grade


    elif 1.0 >= score>=.9:
        print ("Grade is A" + str(intScore))
    elif .9 > score>=.8:
        print ("B")
    elif .8 >score>=.7:
        print ("C")    
    elif .7 >score>=.6:
        print ("D")
    elif .6 >score>=.5:
        print ("F")

# End program
```

Comment: This line: `score = 0.0-1.0` overrides what you got from `input` with negative one.

Comment: `score = float(input ("Enter numeric value of score: "))-1.0`

Answer (score 1):

The `except` part of your script only runs if the `try` part ran into an error. You should have no issues with casting the score to an int so the rest of the script never executes. Why is that in a try-catch block anyway? And why do you want to cast it to an int anyway when it is a number between 0 and 1 and thus not an integer?

You also set your score to 0.0-1.0 which resets it to -1.0, overriding what the user just input. Something like this would work better.

```
import sys

score= input ("Enter numeric value of score: ")

try:
    score = float(score)

    if score > 1.0:
        print ("Bad Score")

    # Use conditional loop to display letter grade based on user-supplied score

    # Print letter grade
    elif 1.0 >= score>=.9:
        print ("Grade is A" + str(score))
    elif .9 > score>=.8:
        print ("B")
    elif .8 >score>=.7:
        print ("C")    
    elif .7 >score>=.6:
        print ("D")
    elif .6 >score>=.5:
        print ("F")

except ValueError:
    print("You need to input a number")

# End program
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however...the script will return the letter gradeEnter numeric value of score: .80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kim /Documents//help 3.py", line 2, in <module>
    intScore = int (score)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.80'
>>>

Comment: I don't see how a try-catch statement applies to this. What error is meant to be caught? The user inputting something outside the valid range doesn't produce an error to be caught.

Comment: I am trying to catch an error if a person inputs a value more than 1.0

Comment: Kim you are using an int(score) instead of float(score). That's why the error appears. Use the code @zephyr gave you in the solution and it will work.

Comment: But that's not a python error. That is already "caught" by your if statement. The error you posted above was because you were trying to cast a string to an int, which will not work. The code I posted doesn't have that issue.

Comment: You need a try..except block around the float(score) there is nothing in a terminal stopping you from inputting anything. If the except is thrown you want to set score to a number outside of your desired range but ensure it is a float.

Comment: Using the following script, I am able to enter a score and receive a letter grade...but I am receiving the same letter grade "A" for every score


score = float(input ("Enter numeric value of score: "))<1.0
intScore = int (score)


if score > 1.0:
    print ("Bad Score")


# Use conditional loop to display letter grade based on user-supplied score


# Print letter grade


elif 1.0 <= score>=.9:
    print ("Grade is A") 
elif .89 < score >.80:
    print ("Grade is B") 
elif .8 >score>=.7:
    print ("C")    
elif .7 >score>=.6:
    print ("D")
elif .6 >score>=.5:
    print ("F")

# End program

Comment: @JoeDoherty You are correct. I foolishly assumed the user would always input a number, but that is clearly the intent of the try-except. Added to script.